# How to access COM variant properties with F#

Tags: c#, f#, com

I have access to a legacy system through an ActiveX control. I can create an instance of this control using it's ProgID in F# and then call various methods successfully. However, I'm having problems trying to use it's properties. These have been declared as Variant types.

I am able to do this successfully in C# like this:

```csharp
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

// asuming I have already created an instance of the Legacy ActiveX control - axLegacy
object v = new VariantWrapper(0.0);
axLegacy.Get("Color", ref v);
```

In F# I can get everything else to work but the property:

```fsharp
open System
open System.Reflection
open System.Runtime.InteropServices

let getParamVal (legacyType: Type, instance: obj, propertyName: string, x: byref<obj>)  =
    let res = legacyType.InvokeMember(name = "Get", invokeAttr = (BindingFlags.InvokeMethod ||| BindingFlags.Instance ||| BindingFlags.Public), binder = null, target = instance, args = [|propertyName, x|])
    res

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let axLegacyType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Legacy.ProgID.1")
    let axLegacy = Activator.CreateInstance(axLegacyType)  // create an instance of the type
    // calling a method with no parameters - works
    let res = axLegacyType.InvokeMember(name = "MethodNoParams", invokeAttr = (BindingFlags.InvokeMethod ||| BindingFlags.Instance ||| BindingFlags.Public), binder = null, target = axLegacy, args = null)
    // calling a method with parameters - works
    let res2 = axLegacyType.InvokeMember(name = "MethodWithParam", invokeAttr = (BindingFlags.InvokeMethod ||| BindingFlags.Instance ||| BindingFlags.Public), binder = null, target = axLegacy, args = [|"method param value goes here"|])
    // accessing a property - does not work
    let mutable propertyVal = new VariantWrapper(0.0) :> obj  // downcast to an Object
    // this throws the COM exception
    let res = getParamVal(axLegacyType, instance, "PropertyName", &magVal)
```

I'm almost there and if anyone can help me that would be gratefully appreciated. I know one obvious answer is to just use C#, but F# actually fits my requirements a lot better. Plus, F# is a cool language to use :)

**=EDIT=**
I managed to sort out the byref bit and added the **getParamVal** function. Following comments I have also generated the IDL for the control and am including the important bits below:

```
    [
      uuid(XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX),
      helpstring("Dispatch interface for AxLegacy Control"),
      hidden
    ]
    dispinterface AxLegacy {
        methods:
            [id(0x00000002)]
            long Get(
                            BSTR lpszParam, 
                            VARIANT* vValue);
    };
```

And the actual error I receive is this:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
  HResult=0x80131604
  Message=Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
  Source=System.Private.CoreLib
  StackTrace:
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeDispMethod(String name, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Object target, Object[] args, Boolean[] byrefModifiers, Int32 culture, String[] namedParameters)
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   at System.Type.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] args)
   at Program.getParamVal(Type legacyType, Object instance, String cmd, Object& x) in C:\Source\F#\AxLegacyConsole\AxLegacyConsole\Program.fs:line 12
   at Program.main(String[] argv) in C:\Source\F#\AxLegacyConsole\AxLegacyConsole\Program.fs:line 25

Inner Exception 1:
COMException: Type mismatch. (0x80020005 (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH))
```

Comment: This is tricky to answer because (for good reasons!) we cannot run the code - can you think of any ActiveX object that would be available on typical Windows machine that would have a similar structure and could be used to debug this?

Comment: Can you show the compiler error you receive?

Comment: Are you sure BindingFlags.InvokeMethod is what you want to use? Usually in COM when calling through IDispatch, there is a different flag. The raw C code value is `DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET` ... so whatever the equivalent mapping is for the BindingFlags is probably what you want to use.

Comment: Have you tried the FSharp.ComProvider? http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Interop.ComProvider/

Comment: Not sure if this will help but there is also https://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Interop.Dynamic/ to help with dynamic invocation

Comment: @TomasPetricek I've been trying to think of something equivalent but haven't been able to so far. I've updated the question to include the important part of the IDL definition. The property is accessed using a Dispatch Interface.

Comment: @JosephWillcoxson it's not strictly speaking a DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET because it has a parameter that's the name of the property you want.

Comment: @brianberns I've now included the error message I get back when I run it.

Comment: @IanOrmesher Believe it or not, you can have properties with parameters. Depends on how it is defined in COM/IDL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved this and it took quite a bit of work! Here's a brief outline:

- I had to create things in Visual Studio 2017 first (which has complete support for F# .NET Framework projects)
- I created an F# Console app (.NET Framework)
- Created a dummy C# Library (.NET Framework)
- Added the ActiveX control to the C# project
- Copied the section to build the Interop assembly from the CSPROJ to the FSPROJ file
- Copied the generated interop DLL to the build output folder of the F# Console app

I've posted in more detail about how I did it here:
[Using an ActiveX Control in F#](https://towardsdatascience.com/using-an-activex-control-in-f-722e4d6614a1)